# Blocking User Process Controller from executing before Control on Winform Fully Loaded and Shown

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I'm creating a Excel VSTO using c#. My operation is easy, just right-click on the cell and click on "Update" and a winform that shows progress status will prompt out and launch the controls on the form is tied to a User Process Controller.

The problem is now that the process has launched and executed before the form is fully load, is there a way that I can block the user process controller from executing before all the control on the progress status form is fully shown and loaded? The image below depict my condition.

I have tried to put my User Process Controller call in Form Activated, Shown, Loaded, and nothing works.

This is the first stage the form loaded. Note : The two line of text has shown that the user control process has been executed.
[image: Form stage 1]

This is the second stage the form loaded.
[image: Form stage 2]

This is third stage
[image: Form stage 3]

And finally it is fully loaded.
[image: Finally Loaded]

Comment: To whom who downvoted, do let me know why is being downvoted for a better question improvement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered a "hack" to overcome this issue. I add in a backgroundworker and done the follow code on the Form Constructor.

```
 public SummaryStatus()
 {
            InitializeComponent();

            backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            backgroundWorker.DoWork += backgroundWorker_DoWork;
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
 }
```

And on the DoWork event of BackgroundWorker

```
 void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
 {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
 }
```

and finally, I added the following code in  Run Worker Completed

```
void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
            UpdateUPC upc = new UpdateUPC();
            upc.txtUpdateSummary = txtUpdateProgress;
            upc.updateProgressBar = UpdateProgressBar;
            upc.UpdateStatusOnItem();
}
```

I understand the above might not be a acceptable solution but it might just provide a workaround for the issue. However, if anyone who has a better solution, do feel free to drop in your suggestion.